# Headline-ignoring, pagewise line numbers

Tags: line-numbering

Despite the easy-sounding task, it appears to be hard to find a suitable package to print line numbers that ignore the automatically generated `section`/`subsection` etc. headlines in their counter.

The currently preferred, non-deprecated choice of line-numbering package seems to be `lineno`, which sadly doesn't have the desired option. My current way of implementing it is calling it using

```
\usepackage[pagewise, modulo]{lineno}
```

before the beginning of the document and then calling

```
\linenumbers
```

after the table of contents so it doesn't interfere with these.

However, using

```
\section{Heading}
text longer than 5 lines
```

results in `lineno` printing the number 5 next to **text line** number 4, because it also counts the section heading as a line. Please note that I'd like to refrain from using the `linenumbers`-environment to manually number every paragraph since my document is quite long.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the maintainer of `lineno` – thanks for the idea. What about using `\Section` rather than `\section` after

```
\newcommand*{\Section}[1]{%
    \par\nolinenumbers\section{#1}\linenumbers}
```

Later, one might "patch" `\section` accordingly, maybe even dealing with the optional argument.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have expected **that**. Thanks for your concern and for providing a fully working solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)