# Omitting white lines from line numbering using lineno

Tags: paragraphs, line-numbering

I am using the `lineno` package to number lines modulo 5 in a document that consists of several sections with lots of small paragraphs (typically 2-5 lines) and with white lines between every paragraph. I would like to only count the lines of plain text, or as my document is simple enough style-wise, I would like to omit section headers and white lines.

Using the response of the maintainer Uwe Lück of the `lineno` package to an earlier question ([Headline-ignoring, pagewise line numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94496/headline-ignoring-pagewise-line-numbers)), I managed to exclude section headers. It involves introducing a new command to replace `\section`. Is there maybe a similar solution, which would save me from inserting a linenumber command after every paragraph?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I imagine you are forcing your "white" lines by means of ``\\``, rather than leaving a blank/empty line in your code. Using the latter approach you can increase `\parskip` (or read up on the [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip)) rather than manually inserting the blank lines.